# let $f$ and $g$ be Riemann integrable functions on $[a,b]$ and $c\in R$ be a constant.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I am having trouble with the following problem.

If we let $f$ and $g$ be Riemann integrable functions on $[a,b]$ and $c\in R$ be a constant.

I need to show that $$\displaystyle \int_a^b cf(x)dx=c\int_a^b f(x)dx$$

What happens if we consider the cases $c>0$ and $c<0$ separately?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi(x)=cf(x)$. Then the Riemann integral of $\phi$ on $[a,b]$ is by definition (I use the usual $1/n$ length partition for convenience, I also assume you can take $\phi$ to be Riemann integrable),
$$
\int_a^bcf(x)dx=\int_a^b \phi(x)dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n\phi(x^*)(x_{k+1}-x_k)
$$
where $x^*\in (x_{k},x_{k+1})$. But this is 
$$
\int_a^bcf(x)dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^ncf(x^*)(x_{k+1}-x_k)=c\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^nf(x^*)(x_{k+1}-x_k)=c\int_{a}^bf(x)dx
$$

Comment: this answers my question perfectly, thanks for your help!

Comment: @user123 certainly! Good luck

Comment: First you have to show $cf$ is Riemann integrable in order to apply the "usual" partition.

Comment: @Vim as noted, I assume $g$ is riemann integrable is given. Saturdays are my don't deal with upper and lower integral days

Comment: yes so this is the complete solution?

Comment: @user123 it depends on context. If your question is to show that $cf$ is integrable when $f$ is and that the integrals are equal, then no. If you are allowed to take that a constant times an integrable function is integrable, then yes.

Comment: @qbert also you mean $cf$ rather than $g$ (the one given in the title) right? It seems $g$ is already given but is irrelevant in the problem.

Comment: I would assume it was the latter, but not sure, thanks anyways!

Comment: I defined $g=cf$, $g$ doesn't seem to show up anywhere in your post.

Comment: @qbert as the title goes, "let f and g be Riemann integrable functions...".

Comment: in your answer It says I assume you can take g to be Riemann integrable, this was given in the question

Comment: @Vim What is your point? there is no $g$ in the rest of the question?

Comment: @user123 I defined $g$ myself, it is not the $g$ in your problem since the $g$ in your problem is not actually defined anywhere. I will edit to clarify

Comment: @qbert thanks again!

Comment: @qbert just noting that there's potentially a notational clash. (Also, OP should remove the unused $g$ from the post to let it make more sense.)

Comment: @qbert last question, have you considered both cases where c<0 and c>0?

Comment: @user123 nothing in my solution will change with the sign of $c$

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward to prove from the definition:

Suppose $c>0$. Let $P$ be a partition. Then
$L(cf, P) = c L(f,P)$ and $U(cf,P) = c U(f,P)$. It follows from this that $\int (cf) = c (\int f)$.

Now suppose $c<0$. Then $L(cf,P) = cU(f,P) $ and $U(cf,P) = cL(f,P) $.
Again, it follows from this that $\int (cf) = c (\int f)$.

Comment: thanks for your submission. Two questions, what definition are you using? and you don't need to factor the integration in until the end?

Comment: $f$ is Riemann integrable **iff** $\sup_P L(f,P) = \inf_P U(f,P)$. I don't understand your factoring remark.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Really, what is wrong with the answer?